# How to use forEach in vueJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, vuejs2, vue.js

I have a response like below from an API call,

[image: response]

Now, I have to repeat the whole arrays inside the arrays. How do I do that in VueJS?

I have searched for using forEach.. nowhere I found forEach usage like key|value pair.

Can anyone help me on how to fetch the values from that arrays by using either forEach or any else(VueJS)?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: It's a single array with 113 entries, it is just Chrome console who show it like this (to be more visible) :D

Comment: Are you displaying the data in the array? If so you should use v-for otherwise you can just operate on the object as you normally would. Vue wraps objects so that it can make them reactive but you can access them normally

Comment: I tried with forEach but no luck. Below answer solved my problem.

Comment: In my case forEach working when I have monopole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **VueJS** you can use **forEach** like below.

```
let list=[];
$.each(response.data.message, function(key, value) {
     list.push(key);
   });
```

So, now you can have all arrays into *list* . use *for* loop to get values or keys

Comment: Code example is completely different from text in answer, and does not even work.

Comment: what do you mean by `$$`

Comment: This isn't a good answer. $$ can be different depending on the project setup

Comment: this guy gave a jQuery answer on a VueJS question

Comment: don't use jquery in vue

Answer (score 31):

You can also use .map() as:

```
var list=[];

response.data.message.map(function(value, key) {
     list.push(value);
   });
```

Comment: `list` is undefined -- even when I declare it. How do I include it within my function?

Comment: let list = [];
response.data.message.map(function(value, key) {
     list.push(value);
   });

Comment: you can loop through a list using map, for sure, but map should be used to invoke a callback function and return a new array (it won't modify the original one, but the callback function can do it).

Comment: if `list` is undefined try using it as `let list = this.YourArrayVariable;  response.data.message.map(function(value, key) { list.push(value); });`

Answer (score 27):

This is an example of forEach usage:

```
let arr = [];

this.myArray.forEach((value, index) => {
    arr.push(value);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(index);
});
```

In this case, "myArray" is an array on my data.

You can also loop through an array using **filter**, but this one should be used if you want to get a **new list** with filtered elements of your array.

Something like this:

```
const newArray = this.myArray.filter((value, index) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(index);
    if (value > 5) return true;
});
```

and the same can be written as:

```
const newArray = this.myArray.filter((value, index) => value > 5);
```

Both filter and forEach are javascript methods and will work just fine with VueJs. Also, it might be interesting taking a look at this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 5):

You can use native javascript function

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key, obj[el])
})
```

or create an object prototype foreach, but it usually causes issues with other frameworks

```
if (!Object.prototype.forEach) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'forEach', {
    value: function (callback, thisArg) {
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('Not an object');
      }
      thisArg = thisArg || window;
      for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          callback.call(thisArg, this[key], key, this);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

var obj = {a:1,b:2};

obj.forEach(function(key, value){
    console.log(key, value)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

In VueJS you can loop through an array like this : 
    const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

```
Array.from(array1).forEach(element => 
 console.log(element)
      );
```

in my case I want to loop through files and add their types to another array:

```
 Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
       if(this.mediaTypes.image.includes(file.type)) {
            this.media.images.push(file)
             console.log(this.media.images)
       }
   }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

> Try This:

```
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  // has access to outer scope `parentMessage`
  // but `item` and `index` are only available in here
 console.log(parentMessage, item.message, index)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you need is flatten an array. Modern javascript array comes with a [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method. You can use third party libraries like [underscorejs](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten) in case you need to support older browsers.

Native Ex:

```
var response=[1,2,3,4[12,15],[20,21]];
var data=response.flat(); //data=[1,2,3,4,12,15,20,21]
```

Underscore Ex:

```
var response=[1,2,3,4[12,15],[20,21]];
var data=_.flatten(response);
```